# Batch FOR loop variable repeat

Tags: loops, batch-file, repeat

so my code is

```
FOR %%a IN (a b c) DO (FOR %%b IN (x y z) DO (echo %%a %%b &pause>nul))
```

but the output is

```
ax ay az bx by bz cx cy cz
```

i want one variable from each loop as `ax by cz` and noting else, please find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define first and second arrays
set i=0
for %%a in (a b c) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set first[!i!]=%%a
)
set i=0
for %%a in (x y z) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set second[!i!]=%%a
)

rem Show elements in both arrays with the same index
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo !first[%%i]!!second[%%i]!
```

The same process with no arrays:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for %%a in (a b c) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set j=0
   for %%b in (x y z) do (
      set /A j+=1
      if !i! equ !j! echo %%a%%b
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A CNT=1
FOR %%a IN (a b c) DO (echo %%a !Cnt! &set /A Cnt+=1 &pause>nul)
```

Comment: Please clarify your post.

Comment: for %%a in (a b c) do (for %%b in (x y z) do (echo %%a %%b)) the output must be ax by cz,

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all wrong .... Try using a sequence of 1 1 3 where one is the step amount so that 1 1 3 would generate 1 2 3... The code is as follows

```
@echo off
For /L %%n in (1 1 3) do (
  For %%c in (a b c) do (
    Echo %%c%%n
  )
)
Pause>null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "a=cat dog horse"
set "b=bad little big"
:loop
  set /a i+=1
  set "x="
  for /f "tokens=%i%" %%a in ("%b%") do set "x=%%a"<nul
  if "%x%"=="" goto :eof
  for /f "tokens=%i%" %%b in ("%a%") do ( echo %x% %%b)
goto :loop
```